# Dynamic Type on iOS7 backwards compatible with iOS6

Tags: ios, ios6, ios7, uifont

I am trying to setup Dynamic Type in my app that should be compatible with 6.1+.
I am using `preferredFontForTextStyle:` and it obviously crashes on iOS <7.0

How are you addressing this?
`respondsToSelector:` and splitting in two every font setting?

Is there a better way?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem, but I specified the text styles in the XIB via Interface Builder.

Answer (score 2):

You can patch UIFont dynamically only if iOS version is lower than 7.

What should you do to patch unexisting method:

1. Prepare your own replacement of unexisting method.
2. Check the OS version - 'respondsToSelector:` is a great way to test it.
3. Add an implementation if method doesn't exist.

In UI7Kit, I patched it using addClassMethodForSelector:... which is provided by FoundationExtension.

See: https://github.com/youknowone/UI7Kit/commit/701c44a69406ad971794c9ab46aeb0cfac1fa207#L3R57

This code add new method preferredFontForTextStyle: from existing method implementation __preferredFontForTextStyle:

Additionally, UI7Kit starts to support the method right now. (in very rough way yet)
Try it if you want.

Comment: I will check your project !

Answer (score 1):

I've been thinking about this; probably the best way to do it would be to manually add the `preferredFontForTextStyle:` method onto the `UIFont` class at runtime if the app is running on iOS 6, and then dynamically pick an appropriate system font size there. The UI7Kit project on github does something like this for other methods, but not this one unfortunately.

Comment: Thank you about missing feature notice. I added rough implementation of it to UI7Kit right now. Any feature request is appreciated in issue page. Thank you!